# How can I implement a SKPhysicsBody object in another SKPhysicsBody object?

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

The scene is: one player and one box, the player is in the box. When I swipe right on the screen, the player runs to the right. When he reach the box's right edge, he will push the box to the right.

So I design two SKNode

```m
    CGRect box = CGRectMake(110, 270, 100, 100);
    SKShapeNode *shapeNode = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
    shapeNode.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:box].CGPath;
    shapeNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:shapeNode.path];
    shapeNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    shapeNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = kbox;
    shapeNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 1;
    shapeNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = kplayer;
    [self addChild:shapeNode];

    SKSpriteNode *player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]   size:CGSizeMake(10, 30)];
    player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:player.size];
    player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = kplayer;
    player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 1;
    player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = kbox;
    player.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
    [self addChild:player];
```

The above initial code didn't work, the shapeNode can't collide with the player. How can I implement a SKPhysicsBody object in another SKPhysicsBody object? and how can I implement my idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: Try using `shapeNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:box];`

Comment: @akashg I tried, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a child node to your box's (in)side and check for contact between player the inside node. When contact is made, move the parent (box) manually for as long as contact is registered. You can move the box with something like `box.position = CGPointMake(box.position.x, box.position.y+1);`. This would be done in the `update:` method.